# How to access raw body of a post request in Express.js?

Tags: express, postman, body-parser

I send this request with postman.

[image: postman]

And I `console.log(req.body)` returns an array like this:

```
{ '{"urls":["https://example.com?paramOne': 'foo',
  paramTwo: 'bar"]}' }
```

How can I get the whole body as a simple string like this?

```
{"urls":["https://example.com?paramOne=foo&paramTwo=bar"]}
```

Comment: try pm.request.body.raw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `app.js`:
Replace:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

With:

```
var rawBodySaver = function (req, res, buf, encoding) {
  if (buf && buf.length) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
  }
}

app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: rawBodySaver }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ verify: rawBodySaver, extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ verify: rawBodySaver, type: '*/*' }));
```