# Missing envelope data from the Docusign webhook request

Tags: node.js, express, docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate the Docusign connect feature. I configured the connect on the Docusign admin page with the public url which is running on a ExpressJs framework. As expected it is hitting my url whenever a event is triggered, but I'm not able to find any envelope related data in the request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you finding any data? Remember that the data payload is in XML format.

### Updated

You will need to look for the raw body of the request.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927090/64904) The encoding will be UTF-8 since that is standard for XML.

### Another update

You have two choices:

#### Using Express directly

You'll need to debug your current software. Next step would be for you to post your Express code. (Edit your question to add your code.)

#### Use a better architecture (microservices)

Does any part of your application run behind your firewall?

If so, then consider using a microservices architecture with a queuing service in between a serverless listener function and your main app, which can be entirely behind the firewall.

Code examples for [AWS](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws), [Azure](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-azure), and [Google Cloud](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-gcloud).

Comment: I'm not able to find any data. The request (body, params, query) are empty objects. The log on the Docusign admin site is fine.

Comment: See updated answer. To make sure you're looking at the right request, add a query parameter to the url you give to DocuSign. eg https://foo.blah.com/listener?test=234 Are you using https? (You must.) You can assure yourself that data is being sent by using an online webhook test app or request bin service